# railway github repository deploy error: 'invalid service name'

Tags: github, deployment, railway

I'd like to use for the first time railway to deploy a small nodejs server for self training and can't deploy the github repository containing the nodejs server files to Railway.
I have logged in Railway with my Github credentials.
From the dashboard, I select "Deploy from github repo",
I click then below on the repository name I'd like to deploy,  and after that I click on -> Deploy Now
I see then a message for a short period stating : creating project and after less than a second, the following message is displayed: Invalid service name. I've googled a bit about this error message without luck.
Any idea ? Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer on the railway discord forum, my github repo name was too long ( mdn-locallibrary-express-tutorial ). After shortening it to mdn-express-locallibrary, the deployment works !